# Retrieve user session details by username

Tags: spring, spring-security

Is there a way I can get details about a user's session (e.g. Authorities) by identifying the suer by the username or some other object?

I know that it is easy to get hold of these details for the current user (e.g. `Collection<?> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities()`) but is there any way I can do something like

```
Collection<?> authorities = authentication.getAuthoritiesByUsername('skn');
```

or

```
Collection<?> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities(principalObject);
```

The use case is that I need to get hold of user's session details through a REST API call.

Comment: But wouldn't that be a security loophole? I mean, the authentication object will be specific for the user who just got authenticated. Unless you have a security token coming in from the REST call and that you have a way to share the authentication between the spring security and the REST call, I think this sounds fishy.

Comment: The REST call will have Spring security checks in place and will be authenticated etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring retrieves the authorities for a user via the [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) interface.

You will typically provide a UserDetailsService implementation bean to the authentication manager, and the manager will make calls to the interface to retrieve user details.

Depending on how you have configured your service, it should be possible to inject the UserDetailsService into any other bean.  At that point, you can simply call loadUserByUsername() to retrieve the UserDetails object for the user and then call getAuhtorities() on it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the answer. I was able to build on top of your suggestion.